# HTML marquee fly over background video

Tags: html, css, video, marquee

I am trying to create a marquee that flies over a background video. However the marquee only flies on the left margin of the video player. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div id="container" class="col-md-6">
        <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?autoplay=1">
        </iframe>

        <div class="flier">
            <marquee>yay 1st comment</marquee>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My stylesheet

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;

}

#container video {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

.flier {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 20px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#container p {
    color: white;
}
```

I hope to have the text to fly from the right end of the video container to the left end. However the marquee only flies on the left end.
[image]

Comment: "What is wrong with my code?" : [Anachronism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anachronism)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The marquee tag has been deprecated since 2008. It is therefore not officially supported in most modern browsers (Internet Explorer being the exception) [[Source]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element). This makes it unlikely to work reliably enough for anything public facing as you can never assume your visitors will have a browser capable of displaying it correctly, or in fact if it will even display at all.

You should use CSS3 to achieve the effect now.

I have found a simple example, on a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/xxuxd/) I will include the code below

HTML

```
<p class="marquee">Your text</p>
```

CSS

```
/* Make it a marquee */
.marquee {
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 50s linear infinite;
}

.marquee:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused
}

/* Make it move */
@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { text-indent: 27.5em }
    100% { text-indent: -105em }
}
```

You should be able to modify this to suit your needs, give it a shot, if you need further help then modify your question or ask a new question with your new code.